# Android connect with php Mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql

I can't figure out whats wrong with this code , it's supposed to get data from php page that i created.
I'm using Eclipse with android SDK.

```
    package com.myproject.myproject2;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class EntList extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.entlist);

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        String jsonString = null;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;

        InputStream inStream = null;

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listtitle);



        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nVPArray = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); //This is empty because you're asking for data
        try{
            //Connect to your script, and save get an object to read the data (inStream)
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://sawtaljabal.com/ar/android_connect/test.php"); // Be sure to replace with your actual script
             post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nVPArray)); 
             HttpResponse postResponse = client.execute(post); 
             HttpEntity responseEntity = postResponse.getEntity();
             inStream = responseEntity.getContent();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("Error connecting", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        try{
            //read the stream to a single JSON string
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream,"iso-8859-1"), 10); // iso-8859-1 is the character converter
               stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
               stringBuilder.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

               String line="0";
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                              stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                inStream.close();
                jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("Error creating JSON string", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }


        try{ 
              //Turn the JSON string into an array of JSON objects
              jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
              JSONObject jsonObject = null;
              for(int i=0;i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                     jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     //do something with the object, like String data = jsonObject.getString("KEY");
                     String data = jsonObject.getString("n_t");
                     tv.setText(data);
                 }
              }
              catch(JSONException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
}
```

I don't even know what to try , can u help me please, this is my first Application.

Comment: what is response in logcat?

Comment: May be you will get `Networkonmainthreadexception`.Because you are performaing network operation inside `OnCreate`. You should use Async task. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: You want me to show you all the errors in the LogCat ?

Comment: yes you need to past the logcat response

Comment: Android apps have a main thread called the UI thread. It is an error to perform long-running and/or blocking operations (like HTTP calls) on the UI thread. Please read this document which explores at least one alternative approach using AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Comment: its better to do the network tasks inside an AsyncTask. Try putting all the code from onCreate into another AsyncTask class and rather invoke the class inside onCreate

Comment: agree with @AtishAgrawal its better to use asynctask for all network work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect `php` using `Android`
first your have to call a web service (which may be a `php` page returning `json`), call to this page should be in `AsynTask` class.
Then you need to parse `json` in right way.

You can try any good tutorial for this. Try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: Welcome, right way to say thanks in http://stackoverflow.com/, is accept the answer and vote up to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first android app you may want to try cloning this project  and learn with code there:

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-jsonarrayadapter?files=1

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the String you are getting in the response is a `JSON Array`. I think it should be a `JSON object` by which you can get the further `JSON Array` .

which means

```
 // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);          
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
```

and then parse the JSON array from JSON Object.

Check Out [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) link, it might be helpful.

Also do all networking call in AsynTask or in a different thread.